# Размытое изображение

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

По какой причине может быть размытое изображение в карточке товара, но когда нажимаешь на лупу и пытаешься увеличить изображение, то сразу перестаёт размывать. Доступа к настройке миниатюры через кнопку "Настроить" нету, возможно есть другой способ?

Ссылка на товар:
https://nellys-charm.com/product/plate-pl3-186/

Comment: Вот почему https://i.imgur.com/5jSvIiC.jpeg

Comment: Хорошо, а как это исправить?

Comment: Очевидно же - выводить правильные размеры изображений, без масштабирования.

Comment: У тебя ширина блока 476px а картинка 435 и width:100%, поэтому растягивает и мылит

Comment: Я что то не могу въехать, вот у меня к примеру есть картинка 683 на 1024 пикселей, что мне нужно ей сделать, что бы не размывало в блоках 476 на 713 (карточка товара) и в самой категории товаров? Подскажите, пожалуйста, буду очень признателен

Comment: Сделать тумбы  476 на 713 и выводить их в карточке товара. Возможно достаточно их перегенировать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Я скачал плагин Simple Image Sizes и попробовал настроить тумбы, но что то ничего не выходит. Вы можете обьяснить по какому принципу это всё создаётся и подгоняется под конкретно товары к примеру?

Comment: В настройке Темы или WooCommerce задаются размеры. Плагины и костыли не нужны.

Answer (score 0):

В Верхней панели есть пункт **настроить** (во фронтЭнде, если авторизованы).

Далее, например в теме Астра, есть пункт в левом меню настроек - **WooCommerce**, где есть пункт **Изображения товаров**, вот там и задаются размеры.

В большинстве тем есть подобная настройка.

Кроме того, можно задать размеры вот тут ВАШСАЙТ/wp-admin/options-media.php

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Да, я нашел эту настройку и вот смотрите, у меня изображение с разрешением с 700 на 1050 пикселей, я ставил тумбы на 700 - размывает, делал немного больше (850) - размывает, делал в два раза больше - размывает и я пытался добавлять новые товары и переделывать старые с помощью Regenerate Thumbnails, но результат тот же, то есть может только как то контейнер поменятся в итоге и всё, что я не так делаю? Вот исходное изорбражение: https://ibb.co/vDWHSWm и ссылка на карточку товара: https://nellys-charm.com/product/plate-pl3-478/  Быть может сам вордпрес режет и ничего не сделать?

Comment: В Вашем случае, дело в том, что у Вас зум стоит. А для зума надо либо второе изображение (в зависимости от плагина или настроек темы), либо надо вставлять по размеру зума. К вопросу изображения и размеров. У меня окно не увеличенного изображения 545х817, но подгружаю я изображение 900х1200 и у меня нормально. Думаю, что исходник у Вас должен быть 800х1200 или около того, но не меньше (700х1050 как у вас, при таком сильном зуме не очень хорошая идея) . Ещё есть нюанс. Картинка может мылиться ещё потому, что она закеширована в wepb и к этому всему у Вас какой-то оптимизатор на лету есть...

Comment: Начал смотреть, рекомендую ещё поработать с карточками товара. В частности, там есть область виджетов **слева** в которой ничего нет. В связи с чем карточка выглядит смещённой от центра. Если ничего не планируется там выводить, рекомендую в настройках темы, указать что шаблон по умолчанию для карточек товара - без виджетов. А там, где они понадобятся, там при редактировании конкретного товара включите и настроите то, что надо. Настройка -> Сйдбар -> Товар (без сайдбара) для темы Астра